# Number Theory cubic residues

Tags: number-theory

1. What is an example of two integers $a, b$ such that neither $a$ or $b$ is a cubic residue mod $19$ but $ab$ is a cubic residue mod $19$?
2. What is an example of two integers $a$, $b$ such that none of $a, b, ab$ are cubic residues mod $19$?

The prof said this will be on the exam. But I couldn't find an example yet.

Attempt: the textbook says that if $p\equiv 2 \bmod 3$, then any $a$ is a cubic residue but I don't know how that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The set of cubic residues mod 19 is
$$ 0, 1, 7, 8, 11, 12, 18. $$
I found this set by computing the cube of all elements.

1. Can you think of two elements $a,b$ not in this set but such that their product (modulo 19) is in this set?
2. Can you think of two elements $a,b$ not in this set such that their product (modulo 19) also isn't in this set?

I can, and I think you can too.